# Adding the date/time to a cell when other cell is updated AND clearing it when that other cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm creating an Excel file for company reports. I borrowed from this [MS Support thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/automatically-adding-the-date-time-to-a-cell-when-another-cell/m-p/264744)

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Or _
    Not Intersect(Target, Range("B1")) Is Nothing Or _
    Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Or _
    Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Or _
    Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1")) Is Nothing Then

    Target.Offset(1, 0) = Now
End If

End Sub
```

It works. Now I want target cells to be cleared after cleaing main cells.

Now when for example I erase A1, the time in A2 stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for an `IsEmpty` check in your code:

```
If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then Target.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents Else Target.Offset(1, 0) = Now
```

As a whole:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:E1")) Is Nothing Then

    If IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then Target.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents Else Target.Offset(1, 0) = Now

 End If

End Sub
```